# Combo box Parity bit

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have a program where the user selects the comport, baud rate and parity bit to establish serial communication.

The parity bit is selected from a combo box (None, Odd, Even).

```
int Parity = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;

switch (Parity) //Parity
{
    case 0:
    port.Parity = Parity.None;
    break;

    case 1:
    port.Parity = Parity.Odd;
    break;

    case 2:
    port.Parity = Parity.Even;
    break;
}
```

This code works fine but is there a more simple way to go around this. Thank you.

Comment: how is the Parity enumeration defined? Can you change it?

Comment: Check the *SelectedValue* of the combo box, not the index

Comment: you can cast from int to enum, but that can sometimes be seen as a bad practise (since if you change something in your enum declaration, your code suddenly breaks)

Comment: If you populate the combobox' values from the enum, you can then cast those values to the enum directly. BTW, I love this clarifying comment: `//Parity`. :D

Comment: You may want to post this code optimization question on one of these sister stackexchange sites - https://codereview.stackexchange.com or https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com

Comment: @STLDeveloper when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat - Appreciate the comment. Please note that I said "You *may* want to post this code optimization question on *one* of these sister stackexchange sites...". Since this question is off-topic here, I'm not suggesting cross-posting.

Answer (score 3):

If you populate your combobox with values of type `Parity`. For example like this:

```
comboBox1.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(System.IO.Ports.Parity));
```

then you can use the [SelectedItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem(v=vs.110).aspx) property because it holds the value with the corresponding type `System.IO.Ports.Parity`! Then simply cast the `SelectedItem`, assign it and the switch/case becomes obsolete:

```
port.Parity = (System.IO.Ports.Parity)comboBox1.SelectedItem;
```

If you have not used the original enum to populate the combobox then this approach will not work.

If you used simple `string` like in this example:

```
comboBox1.Items.Add("None");
comboBox1.Items.Add("Odd");
comboBox1.Items.Add("Even");
comboBox1.Items.Add("Mark");
comboBox1.Items.Add("Space");
```

you can `Parse` them into the enum values and then cast:

```
port.Parity =  (Parity)Enum.Parse(typeof(Parity), comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

I would not advise to use the second approach by populating it with `string`. The first one is more robust. If you do it with an custom defined enum you will incorporate the changes in future. If you soon decide to add values to it, you combobox will extend automatically.

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to change the definition of the enum

```
public enum Parity { Even = 2, Odd = 1, None = 0 }
```

you can cast the result by

```
port.Parity = (Parity)comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
```

Comment: This assumes a certain order of the items populated into the combobox. The code is likely to break and is not as maintainable as could be...